# Change View Title when Navigating Back from a (Sub) View

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a RootView with 5 buttons. When a button is pressed, I change the title of the current view (so the Back Button is brief) before displaying the selected view. When transitioning to the new (sub) view, I send the pushViewController message to the NavigationController through the AppDelegate.

When the Back Button is selected in the sub-view, I would like to change the title back to the verbose title.

Could anyone point out how I would accomplish the title change of the RootView when leaving a sub view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the title in `viewWillAppear` of you RootView:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.title = @"RootView";
}
```

If you use the back button on a sub-view, the root view will get the right title.